# Create a circle polygon in GMaps.Net?

Tags: point, circle, gmap.net

I found this function and converted it to VB.Net. It draws an oval rather than a circle. What do I need to do to fix the calculations?

[image: Distorted circle]

```vb
Dim seg As Double = Math.PI * 2 / segments
For i As Integer = 0 To segments - 1
  Dim theta As Double = seg * i
  Dim a As Double = _pll.Lat + Math.Cos(theta) * radius
  Dim b As Double = _pll.Lng + Math.Sin(theta) * radius
  plls.Add(New PointLatLng(a, b))
Next
```

Comment: What coordinate reference system is your data in? Is the basemap in the same CRS?

Comment: I have idea, this is `GMaps.Net` and I don't have any idea how to check that. There are no tags for this mapping open source. It does use Bing map as the engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it needed as const aspect to be added to the lat.

```vb
Dim seg As Double = Math.PI * 2 / segments
Dim aspect As Double = 0.75
For i As Integer = 0 To segments - 1
 Dim theta As Double = seg * i
 Dim a As Double = _pll.Lat + Math.Cos(theta) * radius * aspect
 Dim b As Double = _pll.Lng + Math.Sin(theta) * radius
 plls.Add(New PointLatLng(a, b))
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your data is in degrees, and a degree of longitude is a shorter distance than a degree of latitude anywhere other than the equator.  I am not familiar with GMaps.Net and the projection features it offers but typically one would convert to a projected coordinate system, generate the circle there, and convert back to degrees.

Comment: I don't have an option to convert it to a projected coordinate system - I thought it was in that mode already. Not really sure though.

Comment: There should be a way with the current math.